# Dovecot permission error creating inbox

Tags: permissions, dovecot

I have a new Dovecot installation, with dovecot daemon running as root (according to ps).

My 10-mail.conf contains

```
mail_location = mbox:/data/mail:INBOX=/data/mail/%d/%n
mail_privileged_group = vmail
```

and my /data/mail/* subdirectories (domain names) are owned by vmail:vmail with 777 permissions.

Yet when my client tries to retrieve mail by pop the dovecot fills with errors like this:

```
Nov 29 00:18:54 pop3(user@mydomain.com): Error: Couldn't open INBOX: Permission denied
```

I'm guessing that dovecot is failing to create the INBOX folder (even though it successfully created the /data/mail/mydomain.com/user folder).  Can someone explain what's wrong?

Comment: What are the permissions on the containing directories?

Comment: /data/mail is owned by root:root with 755 permission.  But since dovecot runs as root and created the next level of directories (domain names) I assumed that was ok

Comment: Actually I might have created the domain subdirectories manually...in case that matters

Comment: I think you nailed it - ownership of /data/mail.  Experimenting to see if that works across all cases

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the root of the mail directory (mbox) must be owned by the mail user, with 750.  After that it worked.

(Credit to Michael Hampton above)